# Return last date by name in SQL operation on Access

Tags: sql, r

I have a table with name and date. I want to return a column with last date (most recent) for each name.
In R should be similar to this :

```
date <- sample(seq(as.Date('2018/01/01'), as.Date('2019/01/01'), by="day"), 12)
name <- sample(c("carol", "steph", "bob"), 12, replace = T)

df <- tibble(name, date)

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(last_date = max(date)) %>% 
  arrange(name)
```

Input :

[image]

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use correlated subquery

```
select t1.* from table t1
where t1.last_date= (
                  select max(last_date) from table t2 where t2.name=t1.name
                    )
```

Or you could use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by name order by last_date) rn
  from table_name
) t where t.rn=1
```

After seeing  the change it seems you need below query

```
select t.name,t.date,t1.last_date from table_name t 
 join    
 (
    select name,max(last_date) as last_date from table_name
    group by name
 ) t1 on t.name=t1.name
```

Comment: thanks, t.last_date should be t1.last_date or i'm wrong ?

Comment: @DimitriPetrenko you are correct it should be t1 :)

Comment: Thanks, but I need a group by because for each name, I want the last date ? is it possible ?

Comment: @DimitriPetrenko  corrent solution  will return max last_date for each name  which is recent date

Comment: yes exactly, but I want to return all names with their last_date not only the names with the most recent date :)

Comment: @DimitriPetrenko could you please share data set and its output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186773/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-dimitri-petrenko).